# Python RoboBrowser error

Tags: python, web-scraping, robobrowser

I'm using RoboBrowser to login to a website using this code:

```
import re
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
bra=RoboBrowser()
bra=open("http://webpage.com")
form=bra.get_form()
form['user']='test'
form['password']='pass'
bra.submit_form(form)
```

But I get this error:

**OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:'http://webpage.com'**

I'v tried all urls related to the site but I always get the same error. Maybe I can use another library or something. I'm using Windows 10 and use Python 3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to access the [`open` method of the `bra` variable (RoboBrowser)](https://robobrowser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=open#robobrowser.browser.RoboBrowser.open). The problem is that you are using an equals sign and are actually calling the standard library [built-in function `open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). Changing the equals sign to a period should fix this.

```
bra=open("http://webpage.com")
   ^
   v
bra.open("http://webpage.com")
```

Comment: Worked but gave me this error:  br.open('webpage.com')                               
                                                                                                 
response = self.session.request(method,url,**self._build_send_args(**kwargs))     
                                                                                         
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'request'